# Using sed to prepend strings to multiple files

Tags: macos, sed

I've been experimenting with sed over the past hour and can't seem to get it working.  I need to prepend a line at the beginning of all python files in a folder, example folder "A".

First I find all python files using find:

```
find /A -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py"
```

This shows a list of python files.  (WORKS!)

Then when I try the following as suggested by some blogs and tutorials online:

```
find /A -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py" -exec sed -i '1i # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-'
```

I get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "/A/buttons.py": extra characters at the end of h command
```

what is h command?  How can this be done properly?

**By the way, I'm using Mac OS X.**

Comment: What is the exact line you're trying to prepend? This worked for me: `find A -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py" -exec sed -i '1i Text to prepend' {} \;`

Comment: I want to add: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Answer (score 2):

Replace your find/sed command with this one:

```
find /A -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py" -exec sed -i.bak '1i\
Text to prepend
' {} \;
cd /A
for i in *.py; do
[[ $(sed q $i) != "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" ]] && sed -i.bak '1i\
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
' $i
done
```

Comment: I don't want a backup.  I want it to directly write into the python files.

Comment: Above command will directly write into your `*.py` files only. It will just create extra `*.bak` files for safety. If you don't want it just remove `.bak`.

Comment: I get an error in the Terminal on Mac OS X:

sed: 1: "1i Text to prepend": command i expects \ followed by text

Comment: Mac version of sed does have its limitations. For instance it requires \ after `i`. You can try the following: `find A -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py" -exec sed -i '1i\<NEWLINE># -*- coding: utf-8 -*-' {} \;`

Comment: Ok, I tried that as well.....but I got this:

    `sed: 1: "1i\# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-": extra characters after \ at the end of i command`  I tried escaping the \ but it was no use either.  What's going on?

Comment: sed with i needs to be broken down in multiple line. Try my edited answer now.

Comment: Ok, your edited answer works! Yay! Now I have another question:  Is it possible to conditionally add that `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line ONLY if it is not in the first line?  So if it's already added, don't add that line, else prepend it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

use the below command.Its working at my place

```
find /A -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py"| xargs perl -pi -e 'if($f==1 or $.==1){s/^/# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-\n/g;$f=0;}if(eof){$f=1}'
```

if you want to use `exec` in `find`

```
find /A -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py" -exec perl -pi -e 'if($f==1 or $.==1){s/^/# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-\n/g;$f=0;}if(eof){$f=1}' {}/;
```